# Can the box made by the <kbd> HTML tag be made smaller?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Keyboard input can be indicated with the `kbd` HTML tag, as in

```
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
```

which displays as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. The boxes created by this tag are quite large, so that they are in contact with the line below, and if such boxes occur directly above one another on different lines they overlap, see [for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133790/586):

[image]

On Stack Overflow these boxes are smaller, so there is no overlap, see [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98846/551171):

[image]

Can a similar design be implemented at TeX.SX? As commented by doncherry this [should really have been done last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117903/162565):

> **2012-05-05:** Keyboard shortcuts (created with `<kbd>`) on all sites are now rendered like they've always been on Ask Different, with a less boxy layout.

But this obviously hasn't happened here.

Comment: This ought to have been implemented for a long time: [“2012-05-05: Keyboard shortcuts (created with <kbd>) _on all sites_ are now rendered like they've always been on Ask Different, with a less boxy layout.”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117903/162565) (highlighting mine).

Comment: Regarding doncherry’s comment and your edit: Isn’t it actuylly a bug then? With the respective tag by any chance a site admin is getting a notice also.

Comment: @Speravir Perhaps, but it could also be that the design team just forgot us when they implemented it at other sites.

Comment: weirdly mobile version has the rounded nicer version. already.

Answer (score 14):

Indeed the CSS tag for the kbd style is given by

```
kbd {
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(204, 204, 204) rgb(170, 170, 170) rgb(136, 136, 136) rgb(187, 187, 187);
    padding: 2px 4px;
    border-width: 1px 3px 3px 1px;
}
```

Tweaking it a little (removing the padding and adding `border-radius:5px;` gives the following which looks quite nicer. I think there are finer settings on the SO version.

[image]

Comment: First, Matlab. Then TikZ. Now CSS. ♥

Comment: @PauloCereda Powered by Firefox developer tools :) Right click and `inspect element` :P

Comment: It doesn't answer the question....

Comment: I don't know why but there were two undelete votes so why not...

Comment: Nice, very nice, but I think the left / right padding has been shrunk a little too much.